# How to run python script?

Tags: python

Say Suppose, the name of my python script file is hello.
How the script can be executed ?
Sometimes, I see that most of the python scripts are executed by (python hello.py) and sometimes (./hello.py). Which one of these executing is true? If both are same, why it is mentioned as different commands?

Comment: they both are same, depending on your operating system and your system configuration either one or both can be used.

Comment: Perl file.py is used by which operating system and ./python.py is used by which OS?

Comment: you can't run python by `perl file.py`, because perl is a different programming language

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax `./hello.py` is typically used on Unix-like systems (including Linux and OSX); it requires two things:

1. that `hello.py` has proper rights (execute bit set)
2. that the first line of `hello.py` is `#!/usr/bin/python` (or similar, depending on location of your Python interpreter)

The other form - `python hello.py` - does not have such requirements.